# Problems open a text file from bash shell to windows software, How to open?

Tags: bash, shell, text-files

What I want to solve is simply open a text file generated by bash in a windows software. Something happen with the format or something like that. I can open the file with notepad, wordpad... but no with a specific software, so something is wrong with the kind of text file, unicode format or whatever..

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your 'specific software' can handle `LF` instead of `CRLF` correctly?

Comment: @Manuel Barbe Maybe no, that´s the problem, I don't know how to add the carriage return and that could be the problem, thanks, you have any idea?

Comment: You may open the file manually e.g. in Notepad++ and choose Edit->EOL conversion->Windows Format (if converting manually is an option) Don't forget to save the file.

Comment: @Manuel Barbe I tried and I can't do that with notepad, anything else?

Comment: Did you use `Notepad++`, not the Windows-shipped Notepad?

Comment: @Manuel Barbe I haven´t sorry

Comment: Any more suggestions?

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: @sureshw nothing special, just "this file type is not supported"

Comment: @Manuel Barbe OK the problem was solve, I installed the Notepad++ and thats it. Thanks Manuel.

Comment: i think you need to convert all ur text file "encoding" to: UTF-8 and it will be compatible with all  os softwares without any problems!

Comment: There's also a utility called `unix2dos` (in the package `dos2unix`) which will do these sorts of conversions for you, in Linux. Then you don't have to do anything special in Windows.

Comment: @Andras Deak cool. Thanks